# SQL Parse error with "on duplicate key update"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have an error with this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data VALUES (1,2,2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE latitude='2'";
```

The error is :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Do you have an idea ? All the examples that I've seen were like that.
And it works in phpmyadmin:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1gXu.png)

Comment: Your INSERT is valid syntax, must be something else...

Comment: The field latitude is datatype int?

Comment: the field latitude is datatype float. I tried this line on phpmyadmin and it works. I don't understand why the '=' is a problem here.

Comment: Are you sure that's an equality sign in your code? :) https://github.com/reinderien/mimic

Comment: Yes i'm sure :) but I solved the problem. The '$' sign has disappeared from "$sql" so the '=' sign which causes the problem was not the one I thought :p
Thanks to all of you !

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The '$' sign has disappeared from "$sql" so the '=' sign which causes the problem was not the one I thought :p Thanks to all of you !